# Is the dg-nerve functor a Quillen equivalence?

Tags: model-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, dg-categories

Lurie defines the dg-nerve $N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})$ of a dg-category $\mathcal{C}$ in [Higher Algebra](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/higheralgebra.pdf) Construction 1.3.1.6: for each $n \geq 0$, we define $N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})_n\simeq \text{Hom}_{\mathcal{S}et_{\Delta}}(\Delta^n,N_{dg}(\mathcal{C}))$ to be the set of all ordered pairs $(\{X_i\}_{0\leq i\leq n}, \{f_I\})$ where:

- For $0\leq i\leq n$, $X_i$ denotes an object of the dierential graded category $\mathcal{C}$.
- For every subset $I=\{i_-<i_m<i_{m-1}<\ldots <i_1<i_+\}$ with $m\geq 0$, $f_I$ is an element of the abelian
  group $\text{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(X_{i_-},X_{i_+})_m$, satisfying the equation
  $$
  df_I=\sum(-1)^j(f_{I-i_j}-f_{i_j<\ldots <i_m<i_+}\circ f_{i_-<i_1<\ldots,i_j}).
  $$

If $\alpha:[m]\to [n]$ is a nondegreasing function, then the induced map $N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})_n\to N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})_m$ is given by
$$
(\{X_i\}_{0\leq i\leq n}, \{f_I\})\mapsto (\{X_{\alpha(j)}\}_{0\leq j\leq m}, \{g_J\})
$$
where $$g_J=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
f_{\alpha(J)}& \textrm{if $\alpha|_J$ is injective}\\
id_{X_i} & \textrm{if $J=\{j,j^{\prime}\}$ with $\alpha(j)=\alpha(j^{\prime})=i$}\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise.}
\end{array} \right.$$

By definition  $N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})$ is a simplicial set. Moreover Lurie shows in Proposition 1.3.1.20 that $\mathcal{C}\mapsto N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})$ determines a right Quillen functor from the category $Cat_{dg}k$ (endowed with the Dwyer-Kan model structure) to the category of simplicial sets (endowed with the Joyal model structure).

$\textbf{My question}$ is: is this assignment  $\mathcal{C}\mapsto N_{dg}(\mathcal{C})$  a Quillen equivalence between $Cat_{dg}k$ and $sSets$? If not, how does it fail?

Comment: Why would it be? This is something like the forgetful functor from ($\infty$-categories presented by) dg categories to $\infty$-categories. There's no reason to expect that to be an equivalence: for example, any $\infty$-category arising in this way has zero morphisms. By analogy, there's a forgetful functor, and even a right adjoint, from $\text{Ab}$-enriched categories down to ordinary categories, and this forgetful functor is also not an equivalence because most categories don't have zero morphisms.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you explain a little bit what does it mean by an $\infity$-category has zero morphisms?